# Cannot get the uri based on a contact's name

Tags: android, character, uri, spaces

I started building my app for api 13, because   I thougth it could be efficient enough for the most users.
But i changed it to api 10. 
Then the following code stopped working `

```
             String empName=data.getStringExtra("name");
             String hourPay=data.getStringExtra("hourPay");
             String key="";
             String id=""; 

            Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, empName);
            Cursor idCursor = getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, null, null, null, null);                

            idCursor.moveToFirst();
            id = idCursor.getString(idCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            key = idCursor.getString(idCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));`
```

The problem is that it works only with contact names written in English or the ones that have just name (not surname)

For example : 
It works for the following contacts :
Express Service,
George,
Maria Mpakou,
Σοφια, 
With no distinction between languages

But when a contact is written in my language (greek) and has space (e.g Αιμιλιος Δημιος) it returns the underneath cursor with index out of bounds.

When i first tried at api 13 worked like a charm. 
By the way my Android.Manifest has utf-8 encoding if that has something to do with it
Please any recomendation will bw helpfull.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search i finally did it with a different way...like asking a Sql query to all contacts

Here is the code:

```
String empName=data.getStringExtra("name");
Cursor idCursor = getContentResolver().query(                 
ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+" = '"+empName+"'", null, null);
```

That worked like a charm!